# How to measure Angular Velocity observed from A non-stationary frame?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, rotational-kinematics

A stationary observer observes a rotating disc with radius 1 at angular velocy w. Let's say this disc is centered at origin in xy plane (all angular Velocity mentioned in this question is around the origin).

The stationary observer also obeserved a different observer M walking with velocity v in the plane z = k and crosses the point (0,0,k) at some time t.

When I go to measure what angular momentum seen by M at the instant t, I find different velocities at the top of the disc and bottom of the disc.

Velocity of a really small section at top of the disc as seen by M = v + 1*w.

Velocity of a really small section at bottom of the disc as seen by M = v - 1*w

As disc is a solid circular body rotating with fixed angular momentum from a stationary frame, the top and bottom velocity should be same. But I'm very confused why these two velocities come different and hence finding it impossible to measure Angular Velocity of the whole disc in this case.